# Can we download the receiver api js library and serve it with our content, or do we have to use the hosted asset?

Tags: google-cast

Can we download the receiver api js library and serve it with our content, or do we have to use the hosted asset?  How often will the library change?

Answer (score 1):

The Receiver API Library: `//www.gstatic.com/cast/sdk/libs/receiver/2.0.0/cast_receiver.js` will be updated periodically.  Minor bug fixes may be done to the file at that URL, so we don't recommend that you download it and host it yourself.

Major API changes will be announced in the documentation, the release notes, and the googlecast-announcments@googlegroups.com list, and the version number will be incremented.

EDIT - updated URL to the latest release.

Comment: Will it be possible (perhaps down the road) to use the Google Cast within an internal network with no path to the Internet at large? Perhaps using the HTML5 app cache/offline mode to allow a receiver to first grab the resources required?